# android studio aapt doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm using android studio in the windows and have apdated it to the latest version --1.3.2 ,but  i meet a problem recently.This is my gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lypeer.handy"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

when i run/clean/rebuilt my project,i told me

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\lypeer\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

so how should i do to solve the problem?thanks any way

Comment: Update your build tools, double check your sdk path.

Comment: Your bug is an error *inside* aapt, so it'll be popped in another console, maybe gradle's one.

Comment: my built tool is 23.0.0 , it is already the latest :(

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But how to solve that?I've checked my SDK location,it is right.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899963/how-to-fix-22-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1