# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResouces' finished with non zero value

Tags: android, debugging

I am getting this following errors while compile my application.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I did clean/build project but it not work and I checked the SDK as well , it's where it belongs to be. Can any one guide me from this issue.

In the gradle file I am using :

```
**compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'**
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: its v4:13.0.0 or v4:23.0.0??

Comment: When i change to 23.1.1 i do still get the same error

Comment: what is your sdk version now..???

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 21 and buildToolsVersion is 21.1.2

Comment: there is a any error in any of your xml files?? some missing source for imageview like android:src="@drawable/cards"  ??

Comment: remove some unnecessary dependency.

Comment: No i have a string <string name="zebi">Zebi i\'ll do it!</string> it keeps telling me the \ is missing before the apostrophe but even if i add it it keeps giving the error. even when i delete the string or change it to something else the string comes back and i get the same error.

Comment: well then download latest  latest version of the build tools. Adjust your build.gradle to use

Comment: Do one thing . File->Invalidate Cashes->Restart.

Comment: Hmm it didnt change a thing, very weird error. I dont have a clue how to solve this.

Comment: wait gives you some links..!!

Comment: Its this answer helps tell me..!!

Answer (score 0):

I have face this type of problem and i found solutions from this answers

[finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)

[how to fix 22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899963/how-to-fix-22-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

[Gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1 (ic_launcher.png: error: Duplicate file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965398/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-ic-launcher-png-error-duplicate-fi)

[Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)