# Getting build error im my application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is my gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sakhi.live_scoure"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile files('libs/awais.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // compile project(':dBPullToRefresh')
}
```

---

While building I am getting this error..

Process 'command 'C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

---

Can anyone help me out to resolve this error?

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix 23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873281/how-to-fix-23-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Comment: Post the entire log

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            shrinkResources true
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false=
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Comment: same issue brother :(

seems like buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" not supporting or needs to installed somehow this.. do you know how to?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"... below your android written in gradle replace these lines and in dependencies change ll to 26.0.2

Comment: I did it..but then it's giving this next error:

Process 'command 'C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: in the defaultConfig block can you add this line : aaptOptions {
            additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
        }

Comment: if it's not working , then i think you have put duplicate resources : You can follow this link and see the nightFurry answer to find the duplicate resources : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899963/how-to-fix-22-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1