# Process 'command 'F:\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue with my existing project. I am not able to solve this issue. I have tried different methods to solve this but I am not getting any kind of solution about it.

```
Process 'command 'F:\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is my app level gradle file...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')

        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }

}






dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    compile 'bg.devlabs.fullscreenvideoview:library:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.jkennethcarino:RTextEditorView:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.rerlanggas:ExceptionHandler:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.5'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.andrestejero:customratingbar:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone please help me, how to solve this issue I have already wasted my one day on this issue I tried many options to solve this issue but I am not able to do this.

Comment: change compile to implementation in dependencies

Comment: ok let me do this

Comment: i did it but it is not working @AbhinavGupta

Comment: Can you update your latest\ API version

Comment: i have updated it to 28 but it was showing error

Comment: Can you check your all files because in any file have some error like in xml

Comment: i have a lot of files but let me check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900651/7319704 check this link\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356322/7319704 check this tooo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898263/7319704 check this one also